# Jquery Autocomplete datos locales o AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, optimización, autocompletar

Estoy usando este [plugin](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) de autocomplete, mi duda reside en que no me decido si proveer la lista de elementos para filtrar vía AJAX o almacenarlo localmente, ya que si es vía AJAX se van a estar haciendo consultas a la base de datos del tipo `LIKE "%queryDelUsuario%"` que por lo que tengo entendido son **muy** lentas cada vez que el usuario tipee en el buscador. Pero no se que tan conveniente sea almacenarlo localmente cuando el numero de elemento incremente a 100.000 (por solo poner un ejemplo).

¿Cuál de las opciones es más óptima cuando el numero de elementos tiende a ser cada vez más alto?

Comment: Con índices apropiados (o si usas SQLS, índex seek), la consulta mejora significatoriamente, reduciendo tiempo, lecturas lógicas y CPU. Ten en cuenta que cuando se habla de "lento" usando Like se habla de muchos, muchos registros.

Comment: Las consultas no son lentas, pero cada request tiene una latencia implícita. Lo bueno es que esos plugins siempre tienen un setting para no gatillar el request hasta alcanzar un mínimo de caracteres cosa de reducir la cantidad de resultados. Supongo que la cantidad de registros es justamente el inconveniente que tienes para proveer la lista de elementos completa desde el frontend.

Comment: Gracias a ambos por haberse tomado la molestia de responder! Me decidí por la opción AJAX, con un mínimo de 3 caracteres y delay de 50ms para evitar la sobrecarga. Además la librería que mencioné tiene cache implícito, así que creo que se la va a bancar siempre y cuando no lleguen a los millones de millones de registros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias almacenarlo localmente al cargar la pagina todo los nombres que consideres de la tabla, y se la pases a lo que se denomina sessionStorage, de la siguiente manera. (sessionStorage es un almacenamiento local que tiene un maximo de 5mb de escritura)

Al cargar la pagina, traer datos de la bbdd, según las columnas que hace la consulta, a esto le colocaremos una variable "datos".

luego con jquery pasas estos datos a la sessionStorage de la siguiente manera:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("datosAlmacenar",datos);
```

Datos en este caso es un json, el cual puedes luego consultar directamente desde la sessionStorage que esta por el lado del cliente ahora solamente.

Si necesitas extraer esta informacion basta con:

```
datosAlmacenados = sessionStorage.getItem("datosAlmacenar");
JSON.parse(datosAlmacenados);
```

ahora que lo tienes en json puedes buscarlo si existe, y si existe, haces la busqueda en la bbdd

PD: Para eliminar basta la sessionStorage, basta con:

```
sessionStorage.remove("datosAlmacenar");
```

Espero haberte ayudado :D

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tomarte la molestia de responder! No conocía sessionStorage, excelente info! Al final me decidí por los llamados a AJAX ya que los datos que traigo podrían llegar a ser mayores a 5MB en un futuro, además que la librería autocomplete que uso tiene caché y otras herramientas que mejoran mucho la performace. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: No hay problema estimado, espero que no tengas problemas con tu proyecto. Exito